# Removing blank lines and comments in Python (w/o Regex)

Tags: python, string, list

I am a beginner (3rd week of coding) and have the following problem:

I want to remove all comments and blank lines from a list created w/ `.readlines()`. However, my approach seems to be wrong and I don't know how to proceed.

**The contents of the `.txt` file is:**

```
subject1: 3.5

# comment hello


subject2: 4.25
subject3:5.20


subject4:           4.75
```

**And my code:**

```
import os

def get_average_grade(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        return None
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        gradelist = file.readlines()
        print(gradelist)
        amount = 0
        for item in gradelist:
            if item[0] == "#" or item[0] == "\n":
                gradelist.remove(item)

    print(gradelist)
```

Output, which should only contain subjects and corresponding grades (Grade in Switzerland contains floats from 1-6):

**My actual output**

```
['subject1: 3.5\n', '\n', '# comment hello\n', '\n', '\n', 'subject2: 4.25\n', 'subject3:5.20\n', '\n', '\n', 'subject4:           4.75\n', '\n']

['subject1: 3.5\n', '# comment hello\n', 'subject2: 4.25\n', 'subject3:5.20\n', '\n', 'subject4:           4.75\n', '\n']
```

**My expected output**

```
['subject1: 3.5\n', '\n', '# comment hello\n', '\n', '\n', 'subject2: 4.25\n', 'subject3:5.20\n', '\n', '\n', 'subject4:           4.75\n', '\n']

['subject1: 3.5', 'subject2: 4.25', 'subject3:5.20', 'subject4:          4.75']
```

As you can see the comments and some blank lines stay on the list of my actual output.

Any help is gladly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you. It works properly as you want.

```
import os

def get_average_grade(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        return None
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        gradelist = []
        amount = 0
        for item in file:
            if item.startswith("#") or item.startswith("\n"):
                continue
            else:
                item = item.strip()
                gradelist.append(item)

    print(gradelist)
```

**Output **

```
['subject1: 3.5', 'subject2: 4.25', 'subject3:5.20', 'subject4:           4.75']
```

Comment: With this implementation I was able to get it to work as well! Thank you for the revision of your first response! `.strip()`was really useful. I wonder why it wasn't taught in my class.

Comment: You are welcome. If it solves your problem, please accept my answer by clicking the tick button.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to strip the lines and skip those that start with `#`.

Try this:

```
with open("sample.txt") as f:
    sample = f.readlines()

print([l.strip() for l in sample if not l.startswith("#") and l.strip() != ""])
```

Then, if you feel like it, you can create a dictionary with all subjects and marks:

```
with open("sample.txt") as f:
    sample = f.readlines()

cleaned_up = [l.strip() for l in sample if not l.startswith("#") and l.strip() != ""]

data = {}
for item in cleaned_up:
    subject, mark = item.split(":")
    subject = subject.strip()
    data.setdefault(subject, []).append(mark.strip())

print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'subject1': ['3.5'], 'subject2': ['4.25'], 'subject3': ['5.20'], 'subject4': ['4.75']}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to get it to work with your help!

Answer (score 1):

Although the other answers try to solve this using list comprehensions I believe it's probably a bit more clear to do it without them.

The code is similar to *ijn's* code except that instead of removing the invalid items from the gradelist, it appends valid items to an empty list.

```py
def get_average_grade(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        return None
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        text = file.read()
        splitted = text.split('\n')
        gradelist = []

        for item in splitted:
            if item != "" and item[0] != "#":
                gradelist.append(item)

    print(gradelist)
```

Comment: Thank you, I was also able to get it to work "your way"!

Comment: No worries, you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the checkmark symbol next to the answer you want to accept!

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read()

subjects = [row for row in lines.split('\n') if '#' not in row and row]
subjects = {row.split(':')[0].strip():row.split(':')[1].strip() for row in subjects}
```

**Output :**

```
>> subjects
{'subject1': '3.5', 'subject2': '4.25', 'subject3': '5.20', 'subject4': '4.75'}
```

The code is pretty simple. You remove all the `\n`, empty rows and rows containing `#`. The you split on `:` and create a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really didn't have a lot of knowledge about dictionaries beforehand and this was a really helpful & short solution to my problem.

Comment: Happy to hear that. You can mark the most suitable solution out of the 5 answers.